# while loop body not executing C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm new to this, please help. I'm trying to write a program for an exercise given by my professor, my professor laid out how the program should roughly look and I followed these steps but the body is still not executing. I've tried a traditional while loop and a do...while loop to get the desired answer but when I enter 7 or higher the body doesn't execute.

a candybar is $1 a piece and each candybar has a coupon and 7 coupons can get one candybar.

```
#include <iostream>
sing namespace std;


int main() {

      int candyBars, money, coupons, bonus, couponsLeft;

      cout << "How much money do you have? ";
      cin >> money;

      candyBars = money;
      coupons = candyBars;

      do
      {

          bonus = coupons / 7;
          couponsLeft = coupons % 7;

      }while(candyBars >= 7);

cout << ("You can buy ") << candyBars + bonus << (" and you will have ") <<
couponsLeft << " left over." ;

system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

After careful thought and thanks to all your contributions, this is what I come up with:

```
do
  {
    candyBars = money;
    coupons = candyBars;
    bonus = coupons / 7;
    couponsLeft = coupons % 7;

    cout << ("You can buy ") << candyBars + bonus << (" and you will have ") 
    << couponsLeft << " left over. \n\n" ;

    cout << "How much money do you have? ";
    cin >> money;
  }while(money != 000);

 cout << ("You can buy ") << candyBars + bonus << (" and you will have ") <<
 couponsLeft << " left over.\n" ;
```

Comment: `candyBars` is never modified inside the loop. It may be endless loop.

Comment: what makes you think that the loop body is not executed?

Comment: When I input 7 the program sits idle, the cout statement doesn’t execute. But if I input 6, it’ll execute.

Comment: It will always be executed at least once, because the terminating condition is checked after the body, not before: it's a `do`-`while` loop, not just a `while` loop. If that's not what you're seeing, then you didn't show us the code that you are really running. But what makes you think that you could ever exit it when its terminating condition never changes? Either you need to change something used in the condition, or there shouldn't be a condition and it should be an infinite loop, but you probably don't really want the latter.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the program line-by-line, watching how the variables change.

Comment: but the `cout` is after the loop. Try to put a `cout << "muh" << std::endl;` inside the loop, or even better use a debugger to see what your program really does

Comment: "the body doesn't execute"? On the contrary, it executes a great *many* times :-)

Comment: I tried the while loop approach, but I always need the modulus statement to execute for my output statement so I switched to the do while loop so the modulus would still execute.

Comment: Is it falling into an infinite loop and not reaching my output statement? I guess going step-by-step would be a wise decision. Sorry I’m new to this, I really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Use your debugger to find out. But again, if it loops twice, it loops forever, because you never change the variable that it checks in the termination condition.

Comment: It somehow looks like you want neither `while()` nor `do`/`while()` if you intend that the loop body should be done always exactly once. (I shortly considered to recommend `if` instead but actually I even don't see any need for this.)